# Ellipsis after a complete sentence

Tags: punctuation, ellipses

I'm wondering how to use an ellipsis after a complete sentence within a quote when not intending to use the entire quote.  Specifically, I'm looking at a Bible verse.  Consider the following:

> "**Therefore confess your sins to each other and pray for each other so that you may be healed.** The prayer of a righteous person is powerful and effective." - James 5:16

I want to quote *and* reference the first sentence (bolded part) of this verse.  I can't simply write

> "Therefore confess your sins to each other and pray for each other so that you may be healed." - James 5:16

because this indicates the the entirety of verse 16 is this one sentence, when in fact there is more.  So I figure I need to use an ellipsis to denote the omitted content, but if I use it like this

> "Therefore confess your sins to each other and pray for each other so that you may be healed..." - James 5:16

that seems to indicate that the sentence continues on after the part I've chosen, when in fact that is the end of the sentence.  So then I think I should do something either like [period-space-ellipsis]

> "Therefore confess your sins to each other and pray for each other so that you may be healed. ..." - James 5:16

or [4-dot ellipsis]

> "Therefore confess your sins to each other and pray for each other so that you may be healed...." - James 5:16

but those both look weird and wrong to me.

So what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I'm sure there's a semi-standard way of quoting part of a verse. The relevant Wikipedia page doesn't help but does mention a (paper) Christian writers' style guide and various other sources.

Comment: The [Catholic Lectionary for Mass](http://catholic-resources.org/Lectionary/1998USL-OrdinaryB.htm), for example, uses a lower-case *a* to refer to the first part of a verse (nominally broken in two parts); so for example the psalm versicles for 18 Jan 2015 are listed as "Ps 40:2+4, 7-8a, 8b-9, 10"; that is, Psalm 40, vv. 2 and 4 (first versicle), verse 7 and first part of verse 8 (second versicle), second part of verse 8 and verse 9 (third versicle), verse 10 (fourth versicle). That's the approach I've seen as standard.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use four dots (with non-breaking spaces book-ending the three dots that represent the ellipsis so they don't break at line-breaks).

http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/SpecialCharacters.html

You could also use a period and a space followed by the single ellipsis character:
`healed. …`  /U2026/

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/ellipses.html), Chicago style would be:

> "Therefore confess your sins to each other and pray for each other so that you may be healed."

MLA style would be:

> "Therefore confess your sins to each other and pray for each other so that you may be healed. . . ."

If you wished to also reference the verse in MLA style, the period would go after the reference:

> "Therefore confess your sins to each other and pray for each other so that you may be healed . . ." (James 5:16).